# Tool which displays Arduino Data

Tags: software-development, gui, programming, hardware

After my first Topic got closed due to inaccuracy im going to try it again:

I'm going to develop a GUI which represents Data (like Heart-Rate)from Arduino via Serial Communication (USB). So the most important thing about my GUI should be that the data is presented in diagrams and Graphs, which can be manipulated (zoom into graph). The GUI should be ran by ".exe" or any other data type which can run by itself.

So for that, i need a Software (IDE) which is capable of creating a executable GUI for (live-)Data.

I heard about the Software "MatLab" but i never worked with it and so im not quite sure what benefits it has.

To clearify my Topic:

1. It runs on Windows
2. The GUI should be executable on every's Person (Windows-)Computer. So it should be for free. If the development of the GUI is chargeable im okay with it (~100€).

Comment: "I'm going to develop a GUI which ... "; so, you are going to code, and your target platform is Windows (not in a browser, for instance). Which programming languages do you know, if any?

Comment: Yes, im going to code. Im known with : Java, Javascript , Android, C# and a bit C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in conclusion we think that this post answers my question : https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1180/serial-data-plotting-programs

It gives a overview of all existing Tools and comments and answers about Software with which you can create a GUI by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> im going to code. Im known with : Java, Javascript , Android, C# and a bit C++.
>
> i need a Software (IDE) which is capable of creating a executable GUI for (live-)Data"

MircroSoft Visual Studio is free and can do that, coding in C# or C++ - if you want a Windows' .EXE app (but I can tell you about charts & graphs).

---

If you want it browser based hat you can get some excellent free charts from [D3JS](https://d3js.org/) - take a look at the [gallery](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/).

You can code that in JavaScript.

---

You can probably also do it in Java (which I don't use), so you have two choices:

- chose a language and edit your question
- search for `free charting` maybe add the word `library` or `component` And look at examples and choose the one you prefer which has a language that you know.

Take a look at [our other charting questions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charts)

---

By the way, you say

> a GUI which represents Data (like Heart-Rate)from Arduino via Serial Communication (USB).

Will every user have an Arduino & serial port? If not, you nee dot think about a server to attach the Arduino to it & read data into a database and then the user clients read from that.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. The thing about VIsual Studio was that i wasnt sure if there is good libary for presenting date into charts and even functionalities for these graphs.  Yes, the User of the GUI will have a Arduino to work with in front of him.

Comment: I am afraid that I also don't know that about VS; but you can google, or search our other chart answers, or wait to see who else posts an answer here. D3JS is pretty amazing, but I personally prefer compiled languages to scripted. If you do google & find an answer, please come back and post it here, to help others in future.

Comment: I have found a similar Question here: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1180/serial-data-plotting-programs

Comment: The answers there could help me and other People probably.

Comment: If you are happy with the other question, we could close this as duplicate, which would lead anyone reading this question in future to the answer. But, if it doesn't answer you fully, then leave this question open (although you might want to edit it?)  The answer there looks good to me, though

Comment: Yes i think its better if we Redirect People to the older post. Thank you for your help. I published a final answer.

Comment: Great! I am glad that you found a solution (although it's always better to search before posting :-)  I upvoted your answer and all of your comments to say welcome